# $\mu (A \bigtriangleup B ) = \mu(B) - \mu(A) + 2\mu(A \setminus B)$

Tags: measure-theory

How can I prove it?:
$\mu (A \bigtriangleup B ) = \mu(B) - \mu(A) + 2\mu(A \setminus B)$

I started with: $\mu (A \bigtriangleup B )=\mu((A \cup B)\setminus B) + \mu ((A \cup B) \setminus A) = 2\mu (A \cup B) - \mu(B) - \mu(A)=... $
Does anyone have an idea how to finish it?

Comment: Note that $A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\cup B$, the latter being a disjoint union.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to prove that $\mu (A \bigtriangleup B )+\mu(A)  = \mu(B) + 2\mu(A \setminus B)$.

But we have that

$\mu (A \bigtriangleup B )+\mu(A)=\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B\setminus A)+\mu(A)=\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(A\cup B)$,

and

$\mu(B) + 2\mu(A \setminus B)=\mu(A\cup B)+\mu(A \setminus B)$,

so they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Use the axioms of measures. Also,
$$
A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)
$$
is a *disjoint* union, and you have the disjoint unions:
$$
(B\setminus A)\cup A=B\cup(A\setminus B)
$$